# Is it way to use blazor component exist in another web application container

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is it way to use blazor component(server-side blazor) exist in another web application container without add this project to my dotnet project.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "another web application container". Are you referring to Docker containers? The use of server-side containerization is orthogonal to use of Blazor which is _largely_ a client-side concern.

Comment: i created two dotnet projects , each project run in docker container and has it's own plazor pages and components.

Comment: i want to make another dotnet project that show pages from these projects and also run in another container, i want to use companents inside theses projects without add them as a project reference